# find and replace string 'NA' with NA when date-type column is present

Tags: r

I want to search all columns for `'NA'` and replace with `NA` but running into issues when there is a date column present:

```
library(lubridate)
x = data.frame(a = c('NA', NA), b = c(today(), today()))
x[x == 'NA'] = NA
```

returns error:

```
Error in charToDate(x) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

How can I get rid of this? I know the names of the non-date columns, tried to do something like

```
col = 'a'
x[x == 'NA', col] = NA
```

but got the same error.

Comment: Try with `is.na`

Comment: Is the value that you're replacing `NA` or is it `'NA'` ?

Comment: `'NA'` replaced by `NA`

Comment: If you are seaching to replace NA in certain class of columns, `library(forcats);library(dplyr); x %>% mutate_if(is.factor, ~ na_if(., 'NA') %>% fct_drop)` would remain the same class i.e. factor with levels dropped

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error comes from the fact that column `b` is date type and "NA" cannot be interpreted as a date

```
x$b == "NA"
Error in charToDate(x) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

The code `x == "NA"` goes through both columns of the dataframe. Try:
 `x$a[x$a == 'NA'] = NA`

Comment: this did it. ended up using `x[, col][x[, col] == 'NA'] = NA` to make it easier to pass multiple columns

Answer (score 2):

If we already know the columns that we want to change we can subset those columns, check for "NA" and replace them with `NA` like :

```
x[col][x[col] == 'NA'] <- NA
x

#     a          b
#1 <NA> 2020-03-11
#2 <NA> 2020-03-11
```

Or to be very specific :

```
x[col][x[col] == 'NA' & !is.na(x[col])] <- NA
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try `replace` like below

```
x$a <- replace(x$a,which(x$a=="NA"),NA)
```

such that

```
> x
     a          b
1 <NA> 2020-03-10
2 <NA> 2020-03-10
```

**DATA**

```
x <- structure(list(a = structure(c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_), .Label = "NA", class = "factor"), 
    b = structure(c(18331, 18331), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: `b` column is a factor not a date in your data

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work with your reprex:

```
na_func <- function(x) gsub('NA', NA,x)
x[1] <- as.data.frame(lapply(x[1], na_func))
```

Comment: This will change the class of `b` so it isn't date anymore