# replace all "N/A" with NA in a data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I want to replace 'N/A' with NA but running into issues when there is a date column present:

```
Error in charToDate(x) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

I tried solution provided here [find and replace string 'NA' with NA when date-type column is present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60625498/find-and-replace-string-na-with-na-when-date-type-column-is-present)

```
chcols = names(dt)[sapply(dt, is.character)]
dt[,chcols][dt[,chcols] == 'N/A'] = NA
```

still get this error

```
rror in `[.data.table`(`*tmp*`, , chcols) : 
  j (the 2nd argument inside [...]) is a single symbol but column name 'chcols' is not found. Perhaps you intended DT[, ..chcols]. This difference to data.frame is deliberate and explained in FAQ 1.1.
```

Comment: Handle this during data import. E.g., `fread` has an `na.strings` parameter. Use that.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: @sindri_baldur Because the code to first get which columns are character suggests that there's more than one column. (And there's no column named `a`, btw, only in my MWE.)

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to use `.SD` and `.SDcols` to refer to the `chcols` columns.

```r
library(data.table)

dt <- data.table(a = c('N/A', NA), b = c(Sys.Date(), Sys.Date()))
dt
#>       a          b
#> 1:  N/A 2022-10-07
#> 2: <NA> 2022-10-07

chcols <- names(dt)[sapply(dt, is.character)]
dt[, (chcols) := lapply(.SD, \(x) {is.na(x) <- x == 'N/A'; x}), .SDcols = chcols]
dt
#>       a          b
#> 1: <NA> 2022-10-07
#> 2: <NA> 2022-10-07
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-07 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: I have never seen assignments to `is.na()`. Personally, I think `x[x == 'N/A'] <- NA; x` is more understandable. However, reading the documentaiton of `is.na<-` this is actually the official way. Thanks for the take away

Comment: @mnist `is.na<-` is a base function, that's what the code is using. It's one of the official ways, it's meant to solve `NA` problems in a more stable way. But yours is, I believe, much more frequent and since the comparison is with a character string cannot go wrong.

Comment: Personally, I've always found the action of `\`is.na<-\`` to be counterintuitive. To me it would seem more intuitive for `is.na(x) <- value` to assign values to `x` where `x` is `NA`, not to assign `NA` on the indices (or logicals) indicated by `value`. While my interpretation of what `\`is.na<-\`` should do is not the issue here, the use of the name `value` for the second argument in its help page is misleading. My two cents: `replace(x, x == "N/A", NA)` makes more sense and because of how the two functions are written, should be identically performant (and reads well, too). \*shrug\*